# Why say "podcasting" instead of "podcast"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

This is the headline:

> "The deal, which reportedly was worth double what was initially known,
> made Spotify a podcasting giant. But controversy followed."

Why did it say "podcasting" instead of "podcast"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *podcast* is a multimedia file; *podcasting* is the activity or the method of managing, distributing, publishing those files.

Answer (score 0):

It's a verb vs a noun. Podcasts are just a noun, podcasting would be making podcasts. Spotify has creators that make podcasts, so it's a "PODCASTING GIANT".

Comment: That answer has already been given.